# How to access workitem link and attachment history

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

I am working with TFS API and trying to create the history tab exactly same as what we see in TFS explorer.

So far I am able to figure our the changes to Fields via WorkItem > Revisions > Fields

I am not able to create the proper history for Links and Attachment changes.
Links have Link Type, Work Item, Comment and Change

I can see the Link type and Comment fields in  WorkItem > Links but how to figure out change and WorkItem columns?

Similarly for attachments.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Given you have gained access to a `WorkItem` "myWorkItem" you can retrieve what you 're after with:

```
 WorkItemLinkCollection LinkedWIs = myWorkItem.WorkItemLinkHistory;
 foreach (WorkItemLink workItemLink in LinkedWIs)
 {
    string AddedDate = workItemLink.AddedDate.ToString();
 }

 AttachmentCollection AttachedTokens = myWorkItem.Attachments;
 foreach (Attachment attachedToken in AttachedTokens)
 {
    string FileName = attachedToken.Name;
 }
```

Comment: That will give me all the attachments to the current workItem. But I am looking for history of attachment changes done to a workitem. We can easily see this info in History tab of workItem in TFS explorer.
For ex, someone added an attachement on x date, deleted on y date, etc

Comment: I see what you mean, sorry I don't have a better option for you ATM. I hope I 've at least covered the Links-Part..